# SQS ReceiveMessage succeeds but gets a null message

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have the following code in lambda to receive SQS messages:
When I inject a message into SQS, the lambda triggers, but says **data.Messages** is null.

```html
function receiveMessages(callback)
{
    var params = {
        QueueUrl: TASK_QUEUE_URL,
        MaxNumberOfMessages: 2,
        WaitTimeSeconds: 1,
        AttributeNames: ["All"]
    };

    SQS.receiveMessage(params, function(err, data)
    {
        if (err)
        {
            console.error(err, err.stack);
            callback(err);
        }
        else if (data.Messages == null)
        {
            console.log("null message", data);
            callback(null,null);
        }
        else
        {
            callback(null, data.Messages);
        }
    });
}
```

It is not obvious what I might be doing wrong. I tried both a fifo and a non-fifo queue

Comment: Please refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/sqs-examples-send-receive-messages.html

Comment: How is your Lambda function being invoked?  I assume you are not [using the queue as an event source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html) because that only works with non-fifo...  but if you were, the messages are already inside `event` -- you wouldn't use `receiveMessages()`.

Comment: Are there actually messages available in the queue? What you are describing sounds like correct behavior if the queue is empty.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thank you - that was indeed the problem. I was using the queue as an event source, and then doing a receivemessage() on it, which is not needed. I

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When [using an SQS Queue as a Lambda event source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html), a component of the Lambda service actually polls the queue and passes the message payload to the function invocation, in an array `event.Records`, which will contain one or more messages from the queue.  The messages are temporarily invisible in the queue (they are "in flight").

You don't need to interact directly with SQS in this application.

You process the messages and exit the Lambda function  successfully and all the messages just given to you are automatically deleted from the queue by the Lambda poller.

If an exception is thrown, all the messages you were just handed are set back to being visible in the queue.